# Group feedback by category and limit between date range

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Feedback belongs to Category and has `scope :between, ->(start_date, end_date) { where(created_at: start_date.beginning_of_day..end_date.end_of_day) }`

Question is, how do we get the count of feedbacks grouped by category and scoped to a certain date range to get something like:

```
1.5.2013 - 31.5.2013
Good       3
Bad        10
etc.
```

I got so far: `Category.group(:name).joins(:feedbacks).count`, but I'm stuck on how to plug the between date condition there.

Answer (score 1):

```
Feedback.between(sd,ed).joins(:category).group("categories.name").count
# => {"Good" => 3, "Bad" => 1}
```